# Referencing a variable based on a combination of strings?

Tags: actionscript-3

I don't really know how to word this.

If I have mutliple variables like

```
var aHeight:Number = 30;
var bHeight:Number = 43;
var cHeight:Number = 02;
var dHeight:Number = 60;
var aHeight:Number = 20;
```

and I make a function like

```
function (mc:MovieClip,heightLetter:String) {
     mc.y = ?;
}
```

if I just want to reference the letter but not the whole variable is there a way to find it like

```
[heightLetter+"Height"]
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can, if these vars are in fact object properties, that is, they are declared outside any functions, and are thus available via `this.aHeight` etc. And then indeed, you use `this[heightLetter+"Height"]` to get the required variable. Although it would be better that you use an array instead.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I guess an array could work. The example I gave isn't my actual code just an example I made up.